# Resolution scaing for online snake game

Tags: java, scale, resolution

Im trying to add multiplayer to my snake game so that two players can compete to 
get the most apples. my current dilema is: How do i deal with a session where the two players are playing on masively different resolutions? the thing is that the snake game is not currently using a grid. I want to make sure that regardless of 
the resolution the time that it takes for the remote player to reach the apple is the same time that it takes for the one im seeing on my screen!

I hope you guys understand me, if not please feel free to ask me questions. 
here is a picture of the game:
http://postimg.org/image/js8bs4w0b/

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a measurement system, and base the speed the snake travels on that system, for instance, imagine a rectangle with 30x40 blocks, the snake travels at 1 block every few seconds, no matter the size of the block in real life, the snake's speed will adjust to the blocks positions on the game screen.

Comment: ok i think i get it! here is the thing. the snake travels at one pixel per second but in order to make it faster iterate the speed 6 times in a 60fps gameloop. if lets say i run a resolution 1920*1080 and player 2 runs a resolution of 1366*768 i kind of know how to scale it so that he travels at a speed relative to mine. but that doesnt seem to work so well .                                                                                                                                      .would you mind giving me a simple pseudo code example =)? I really wanna get this working!

Comment: what do you think of maybe doing like this: when i get the x and y coordinates from the remote player maybe I have to multiply them by my resolution scale before i translate them into my screen !!??

Comment: @Eudy Contreras:  You would pass blocks back and forth.  Think of your screen as a two dimensional array.  If the snake head is in block[4][5], then you draw the snake head in block[4][5].  Your drawing code would know the size of the block.  It might be 45 x 45 on your screen and 32 x 32 on his screen.  That way, only the drawing code has to worry about x, y coordinates.  All messages back and forth are in blocks.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I like that idea of thinking of it as a two dimensional array, but he would have to rewrite everything if he wanted to use x and y only for his drawing code, where his idea to multiply by a resolution scale if easier to implement, also easier to understand as you follow through.

Comment: I thank you both for your input. I will keep trying different solutions and see what works best =)